# VmRSS increases

Tags: linux

I am executing a multi threaded c++ application on redhat linux.

While the application is running, I observed that VmRSS increases about 20-80 kB and as this value increases, over a period of time the VmSize also increases and results in Out of memory.

VmStk and VmData values remains constant.

**What could be the reason for the increase of VmRSS value ?** 
There are appropriate new & delete operations in the code.

Does this value increase with large operations on containers / due to more number of threads in the application ? or does the value increase if there is any memory leak ?

If the VmRSS does increase with usage of an application then how to prevent the Out of memory situation ?

I know that VmRss is the actual physical memory that is in use.
It would be helpful if some one can provide more information on VmRSS.

Thanks!

Comment: The most obvious culprit is a memory leak.

Comment: *There are appropriate new & delete operations in the code.* Did you actually verify this via Valgrind or a similar tool?

Comment: was this issue resolved. I have the same issue, VmRSS increases but the memory profiler tools report no uncollectible objects/mem locations. They seem to report that all new objects created are collected. via @pm8

Comment: thanks @RichardSlater

Comment: adding to my previous comment, so is this a memory leak. I thought it was a leak, but the tools i am using report as no leak